# How to retrieve clicked list view row data and hide id column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to retrieve all data from clicked ListViews row. Also to hide that id column if it's possible. I tried to use commands with click event and pass that id field into the commandParammeter but no success.

Also searched for other approaches but nothing. Just for information, I need this functionality to show detailed information about each clicked user into other listView so this data would be much easier to view for other users.

*Conclusion:* Need to get clicked row data and if it's possible, also hide that id column.

**Xaml code:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="grdUsers">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Hidden_Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And inside my ViewModel is placed a UserList.Any kind of elegant approach will do that gets the clicked row data.

### Edit

I looked into the link that @BradleyDotNET gave and the code now looks like this.

```
<ListView x:Name="lBoxUser" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="300"           
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  Visibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectionChanged="lBoxUser_SelectionChanged">
                  //this part hasn't changed
</ListView>
```

*SelectedValuePath*: attribute that will bind one of the userList object. In my case it is 'Id'.

*SelectionChanged:* just adding event handler that will execute on selection changed event and get all selected row data. I know it would be more elegant to user MVVM pattern but Commands somehow didn't work for me.

Also to display that 'SelectedValue'.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=lBoxUser}"/>
```

### Edit 2

I found much easier way to do it.

```
<ListView.SelectedItem>
   <Binding Path="UserProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</ListView.SelectedItem>
```

Just added User class property inside my ViewModel and thats all. It gets all selected user data. Also now it counts as MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are well on your way!

To get rid of the "ID" column, its pretty easy; just delete it!

```
<ListView x:Name="lstUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="grdUsers">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

To get the information for the currently selected item, look at the `SelectedValue` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)) property of `ListView` it will hold the bound object of the currently selected item.

Comment: Thanks for response, i will look into that link what you gave me @BradleyDotNET and inform you if it works.